# How to automatically update security group when eks scale worker node?

Tags: amazon-eks

I have ec2 in region A, and eks in region B, eks worker nodes need access a port exposed by ec2, i manually maintaining the ec2 security group which public ip(eks worker ip) can access ec2. The issue is i need update the ec sg manually once scale or upgrade eks node group. there should have a smarter way. i have some ideas, anyone can give some guidance or best practice?

solution 1: use lambda cron job monitor ec2 auto scale group, then update sg.

solution 2: in kubernetes, monitor the node change, use oicd update sg.

note: ec2 and eks in different region.